# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 en juego de Ahorcado

Tags: java, netbeans

soy algo nuevo en programación, y estoy haciendo un juego de ahorcado en Java con NetBeans, pero al intentar imprimir las letras que el usuario va poniendo correctas dentro de un Label, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at juegoahorcado.Ahorcado.palabraFacil(Ahorcado.java:28)
    at juegoahorcado.Ahorcado.txtPalabraActionPerformed(Ahorcado.java:113)
    at juegoahorcado.Ahorcado.access$000(Ahorcado.java:8)
    at juegoahorcado.Ahorcado$1.actionPerformed(Ahorcado.java:68)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1668)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Soy muy nuevo en esto y la verdad no sé que sea, ¿alguien tiene una idea de cuál es mi error o qué es lo que me falta agregar?
Espero haber explicado bien mi problema, cualquier ayuda o consejo para mejorar es bien recibido acá está el código del programa:

```
    private void palabraFacil(){
    String[] palabras = {"cara","popo","pato","gato","duro"};
    int palabraRandom = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (palabras.length));
    String palabra = palabras[palabraRandom];

    char [] palabraUsuario = palabra.toCharArray();
    char [] letraFinal = new char [palabraUsuario.length];
    char letra = txtPalabra.getText().charAt(0);

        for (int i = 0; i <palabras.length; i++) {
            if(palabraUsuario[i]==letra){
                 letraFinal[i]=letra;
            }
        }
     lblPalabra.setText(String.valueOf(letraFinal));

    }

private void txtPalabraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        palabraFacil();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en el `for`

```
for (int i = 0; i <palabras.length; i++) {
  if(palabraUsuario[i]==letra){
    letraFinal[i]=letra;
  }
}
```

`palabras.length` retorna un valor de 5 (indice máximo 4)
palabraUsuario es un char array de longitud 4 (indice máximo 3)
por lo que al momento de llegar al indice 4 del arreglo palabras (en el `for`), en el `if` interno la validación `palabraUsuario[i]` (que seria `palabraUsuario[4]`) trata de acceder a una posición que no existe en el char array.

Comment: ¿Entonces podría solucionarlo poniendo de límite i<4 en lugar del palabras.length? O estoy entendiendo mal? por cierto gracias por la ayuda, no soy muy bueno con esto de los arreglos

Comment: El `for` deberia estar limítado por el tamaño del arreglo `palabraUsuario` algo como `for(int i = 0; i < palabraUsuario.length; i++ )`